# Displaying a component data

Tags: talend

I have a job flow like this,

**tAccessInput_1 --> tMap_1 --> tSortRow_1 --> tJava --> tBufferOutput_1.**
Is this possible to display the data in **tBufferOutput_1** in tJava component at every iteration. If possible how can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just output whatever gets input into the tBuffer component, try connecting to a **tLogRow** component which will spit out everything in the console.

If you want tJava for some other specific reason, here's a slightly convoluted method:

tBufferOutput_1 -> tFlowToIterate -> tIterateToFlow -> tJava

Then, in tJava, you can do the following:
System.out.println((String) globalMap.get("row.column"));

where:

*row* is the name of the main data row between tIterateToFlow to tJava (e.g. row6)

*column* is whatever schema column you want to output

The data is cast into a String, but in your case it may be an integer or something else.

The reason you need to change the flow to an iteration is because tJava needs to iterate in order to print all rows (as you correctly pointed out in your question).

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [llaen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559134/displaying-a-component-data/13566731#13566731) the best solution is to use **tLogRow** to print each row in the Talend/Java console.
If you want to customize the way it is printed, you should better use a tJavaRow (instead of tJava) to avoid the use of tFlowToIterate and tIterateToFlow

tAccessInput_1 --> tMap_1 --> tSortRow_1 --> tJavaRow --> tBufferOutput_1

Then, in tJavaRow, use the following java code : System.out.println(input_row.column)

Where :
*input_row* will be automatically interpreted and replaced by the Talend Code generator
*column* is whatever schema column you want to output